# How to prevent output truncation when importing large Graphics?

Tags: graphics, front-end, import

The `Evaluation` Preferences in *Mathematica* specify a maximum output size of `1048576` Bytes before truncation occurs. That makes a lot of sense when thinking about large lists of data, but is causes trouble when displaying large `Graphics`.

Here is an example. It is produced using version 9.0.1.0 on a MacBook Pro with Retina display running OS X 10.7.5. I'm importing a `PDF` file with a large polygon count.

```
Export["t1.pdf", Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]];
First@Import["t1.pdf"]
```

[image: large output]

This truncation warning does nothing to save space in the notebook, and the full output is in fact generated. So it would be nice if one could automatically suppress the truncation warning which serves no purpose here.

I don't think it's a valid solution to just increase the truncation Byte limit above its default value, because that would affect regular data output as well, and I don't want to increase the limit for that case.

Normally I would of course avoid exporting and importing `PDF` from 3D graphics, but it can't always be avoided if you have an external `PDF` file you'd like to display in the notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the best I could do on short notice:

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "t1.pdf"}], 
  Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]

t1 = First@Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "t1.pdf"}]];

Print[t1]
```

It's not elegant, but it does suppress the truncation warning.

Comment: Good work-around.

Comment: @Jens. I was surprised to find that `Block[{$OutputSizeLimit = 10^8}, t1]` did not work, but a simple `Print` did. I wonder why `Print` is immune to output truncation?

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't think it's that surprising. `Block`just returns `t1`, which is then evaluated by the front end, where  `$OutputSizeLimit` has the old value.

Comment: @Ajasja. Of course. I wasn't thinking clearly.